# How to add parameter to url for every page in JSF?

Tags: jsf, url, url-parameters

I want to add a parameter to every page in my application in order to recognise users by url. Url parameter will be user specific and it will occur in every page url.

Comment: Please have a look at a proper security framework. Shiro for example. It does a great job in our JSF applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameter to your url as follows

```
/myPage.jsf?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true&ua=V
```

and later you can set that value to your jsf bean using `<f:viewParam>` component as follows

```
<ui:define name="metadata">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="ua" value="#{myBean.userActionFromUrl}"/>
        </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```